# Why DateTime Field save time into Database decrease 1 value with data into HTML(Django python Models)

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I try to set time from html into database(apps.model). But When I save date, time is decreased 1. I fill into html 23/07/1996 but SQLite save with 1996-07-22 17:00:00. Is it because of timezone ??? How to fix it?

Please help me.

```
dateOfBirth = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(),blank=True,null= True)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You ask if it's a timezone issue, but have you looked for ways to determine what the timezone is for both the database value and the value that gets passed to the model? Also, no shame in asking a more senior developer for help.

Comment: time_fix = datetime(year_change_int, month_change_int, day_change_int, 20, 8, 7, 127325, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)    Fix DONEEEEEE. Thanks